# all error path in php

Tags: php, error-handling

Please help me, I have set up error logs via htaccess:

```
php_flag log_errors On
php_value error_log errors/log/errors_log.txt
php_flag display_errors On
php_value error_reporting 6135
```

It works fine, but there is a small problem, f.e. I have my own function, which is used nearly in all scripts on my web and inside this function happen this error:

```
[24-Apr-2012 23:33:11] PHP Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /path/public_html/req/functions.php on line 200
```

and now problem is I do not know in which script this error happen, it only shows the path, where function is declared, but do not show the way, where passing variable inside this function this error cause.

Is here any easy way how to show all paths for error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would look for the function 'trim' inside this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error handling function you could use [`debug_print_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) or [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).